# Java Web/JSP program with code running in background 24/7

Tags: java, jsp

What is the best way to implement a notification system that keeps running in the background?

This system will generate these notifications when certain conditions are met. The server has to monitor the database constantly for these events and update a notification log when they occur. When a notification is generated, an SMS is sent to designated people.

With a traditional JSP system, the code only runs when a user visits the site. How do you program the server to have the code running 24/7? Also, how do you feed back these events asynchronously to the front end so the front end does not need to keep polling the database?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague, but i'd say you need a task scheduler, some application servers  like wildfly already have a task scheduler, or you can use something like [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), and set it to run every as many times as you need.